# Shortening a date with angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have a date coming across in this format: Tue, 05 Aug 2014 13:14:25 +0000

I need to trim the date so it reads Tue, 05 Aug 2014. I would like to trim off everything after the year.

I am trying to do this but in angular:

```
var date = item.pubDate;
var datelength = date.length;
date = date.substring(0, datelength - 14).trim();
```

Comment: Is the date a string or a real date?  If it's an actual date, check out the angularJS date filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: I believe it is coming across as a string from word press. I tried manipulating it with the date filters and it didn't change anything.

Comment: They you'll most likely have to resort to basic string manipulation in JS. `yourDate.substr(0, yourDate.indexOf(':')-2).trim()` Would probably be pretty safe.

Comment: I prefer using momentJs http://momentjs.com/ for alle Date formatings in JavaScript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, the Angular way is to parse Date from string and apply `date` filter on it with format you want:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$filter',
  function($scope, $filter) {
    var pubDate= new Date('Tue, 05 Aug 2014 13:14:25 +0000');
    alert($filter('date')(pubDate, 'EEE, dd MMM yyyy'));
  }
]);
```

Or if you want to display this date on view, you can use filter in place:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('HomeController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.pubDate = new Date('Tue, 05 Aug 2014 13:14:25 +0000');
  }
]);

{{pubDate | date:'EEE, dd MMM yyyy'}}
```